# useraccounts - How to remove the accounts-password options?

Tags: meteor

I would like to have Google sign in only, but a package I am using has a dependancy on `accounts-password` (`yogiben:pretty-emails`).
Is there a way to remove the email/password options from the `useraccounts` forms?

Comment: You could always create your own custom login template

Comment: Doesn't look like there is one right now. I would recommend opening a GitHub issue.